# Fixed length generic cache class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have to create a fixed-length generic cache class in C#.
Cache: On addition of new element in the cache, when it is full oldest element overwrites.

I'll be very grateful if anyone can help with this. I am very new to programming.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why **specifically** do you want it to be fixed length? _I ask since that is odd for a cache._

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Queue Datastructure c# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=netframework-4.8). It helps you in implementing the cache based on your requirement. In specific it is called LRU cache implementation.